# sugarcrm custom save function when task is created from subpanel

Tags: function, save, overriding, task, sugarcrm

When a task is created from **Case page (Activities subpanel**), it always call `action_save` function defined in `root/modules/Tasks/Task.php` file where as I want it to call `action_save` function defined in `root/custom/modules/Tasks/controller.php` (or in a file which is upgrade-safe) file. When task is created/edited from Task main page then it calls for `action_save` function defined in `controller.php` file.

Thanks-

Comment: Do you really need to override the action_save() controller method? Have you tried using SugarCRM Logic Hooks? You'll probably be able to do what you need using a before_save or after_save hook: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/03_Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/00_Introduction